# Python 3.5.1 isinstance fails onlists and subclasses of Iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

using third-party library I bump in strange behaviour between Python3 versions.
The following code

```
from typing import Iterable
class Subiter(Iterable):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
print(isinstance([], Subiter))
```

returns True in Python 3.5.1 and False in Python 3.5.3 (didn't test in 3.5.2). It can cause serious bugs, because one can later take attribute of Subiter class and get AttributeError. I search changelog between versions, but can't be able to find related issue or PEP (one candidate is [bpo-24635](https://bugs.python.org/issue24635), but is seems different). Can anybody point me the right issue if it really the bug? Can this situation be avoided only by using additional condition checks? Thanks

UPD: @ekhumoro confirm that it returns False in 3.5.2, so it *should* be in 3.5.2. release notes

Comment: FWIW, it prints `False` in Python 3.6.0.

Comment: `Subiter` isn't in `list`'s `__mro__`, so it shouldn't print `True`...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Indeed! So it's a good thing that the bug's been fixed. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, I assume it will be `False` in every version >=3.5.3, but the whole thing still confuse me

Comment: I can confirm it always returns `True` in **3.5.1**. and always returns `False` in **3.5.2**. So that narrows it down a little bit, but I cannot find any obviously related issues on the bug tracker.